# Create a tableview with directories and files listing in monotouch

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a tableview that lists the files and directories in the documents folder. When a directory is selected it the app should then show the list of files in the selected directory. Its like nesting of tableviews. Unfortunately I am able to create a table view with the files in a specific directory only. I cannot make it list the directories and also list the files in the subdirectories.

I hope have made my objectives clear. Basically I just want to create a document/folder explorer using table view.

Please provide me with code if you can.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few existing examples out there of how to achieve a recursive directory / file listing application using MonoTouch.

See example 1, [an app to navigate up down folders and alert message on file click](https://github.com/SuperYeti/MonoTouch.DirectoryRecurser)

And example 2, [a worked example of how to navigate / recurse the files and folders using MonoTouch](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_the_File_System)

Hope that helps you get on the right track.